# RTF date stamp converted to a DateTime format and vice versa in .NET

Tags: date, rtf, richtext

Does anyone know in which datetime format is represented the date stamp in the RTF?

For example: 
If you have a comment in a Word document dated from "1970-01-01T00:00:00" and you export the document in rich text formatted document, the DateTime above will be parsed as: "-2074015744".

If the date in the RTF was represented in UNIX time it should be "0000000000", so I think that this is not the right format.

To be more concrete: Let's say we have the following part of a RTF doc:

```
{\*\atrfstart 37360238}{\*\atrfend 37360238}{\*\atnid JD}{\*\atnauthor John Doe}\chatn{\*\annotation{\*\atnref 37360238}{\*\atndate 1730446516}\pard\s0\ltrpar\sl276\slmult1{\ltrch\i0\b0\strike0\ulnone sample comment}{\ltrch\i0\b0\strike0\ulnone\par}}
```

the date of the annotation is represented by {*\atndate 1730446516} group. We want to parse the integer which is preceded by the control word \atndate in DateTime format.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this and have found that the LibreOffice folks solved it. The problem involves a lot of bitshifting. The negative number for 1970 was integer unsigned / signed misinterpretation.

See Line #726 of https://docs.libreoffice.org/sw/html/writerwordglue_8cxx_source.html

```
  726 long DateTime2DTTM( const DateTime& rDT )
  727         {
  728         /*
  729         mint    short   :6  0000003F    minutes (0-59)
  730         hr      short   :5  000007C0    hours (0-23)
  731         dom     short   :5  0000F800    days of month (1-31)
  732         mon     short   :4  000F0000    months (1-12)
  733         yr      short   :9  1FF00000    years (1900-2411)-1900
  734         wdy     short   :3  E0000000    weekday(Sunday=0
  735                                                 Monday=1
  736         ( wdy can be ignored )                  Tuesday=2
  737                                                 Wednesday=3
  738                                                 Thursday=4
  739                                                 Friday=5
  740                                                 Saturday=6)
  741         */
  742 
  743             if ( rDT.GetDate() == 0L )
  744                 return 0L;
  745             long nDT = ( rDT.GetDayOfWeek() + 1 ) % 7;
  746             nDT <<= 9;
  747             nDT += ( rDT.GetYear() - 1900 ) & 0x1ff;
  748             nDT <<= 4;
  749             nDT += rDT.GetMonth() & 0xf;
  750             nDT <<= 5;
  751             nDT += rDT.GetDay() & 0x1f;
  752             nDT <<= 5;
  753             nDT += rDT.GetHour() & 0x1f;
  754             nDT <<= 6;
  755             nDT += rDT.GetMin() & 0x3f;
  756             return nDT;
  757         }
  758
```